# crud delete all rows

Tags: php, sql, database, crud

I'm trying to delete all rows from my database using crud and this is my delete response page.
I tried the query delete * but that didn't work so I've manually typed it up like this. The values are coming up as unidentified indexes. Can anyone help, tell me what I'm doing wrong or give an easier method please?

```
<?php 
include "library.php"; 
include "database.php";
?>


<?php
//Get data from form
$faculty=$_POST["faculty"];
$date=$_POST["date"];
$modulecode=$_POST["modulecode"];
$moduletitle=$_POST["moduletitle"];
$school=$_POST["school"];
$modulebookcontent=$_POST["modulebookcontent"];
$moduleorganisation=$_POST["moduleorganisation"];
$lrcmaterials=$_POST["lrcmaterials"];
$moduledifficulty=$_POST["moduledifficulty"];
$modulesimilarity=$_POST["modulesimilarity"];
$contentinteresting=$_POST["contentinteresting"];
$previousknowledge=$_POST["previousknowledge"];
$understoodassessmentrequirements=$_POST["understoodassessmentrequirements"];
$assessmentmethod=$_POST["assessmentmethod"];
$markedwork=$_POST["markedwork"];
$ML_interestforsubject=$_POST["ML_interestforsubject"];
$ML_contentclear=$_POST["ML_contentclear"];
$ML_appropriateteachingpace=$_POST["ML_appropriateteachingpace"];
$ML_reachableforadvice=$_POST["ML_reachableforadvice"];
$ML_helpfulfeedback=$_POST["ML_helpfulfeedback"];
$L1_interestforsubject=$_POST["L1_interestforsubject"];
$L1_contentclear=$_POST["L1_contentclear"];
$L1_appropriateteachingpace=$_POST["L1_appropriateteachingpace"];
$L1_reachableforadvice=$_POST["L1_reachableforadvice"];
$L1_helpfulfeedback=$_POST["L1_helpfulfeedback"];
$L2_interestforsubject=$_POST["L2_interestforsubject"];
$L2_contentclear=$_POST["L2_contentclear"];
$L2_appropriateteachingpace=$_POST["L2_appropriateteachingpace"];
$L2_reachableforadvice=$_POST["L2_reachableforadvice"];
$L2_helpfulfeedback=$_POST["L2_helpfulfeedback"];
$moduleleader=$_POST["moduleleader"];
$lecturer1=$_POST["lecturer1"];
$lecturer2=$_POST["lecturer2"];
$indpstudy=$_POST["indpstudy"];
$attendance=$_POST["attendance"];
$bestfeatures=$_POST["bestfeatures"];
$improvemodule=$_POST["improvemodule"];


$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where faculty=".$faculty; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where date=".$date; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where modulecode=".$modulecode; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where moduletitle=".$moduletitle;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where school=".$school; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where modulebookcontent=".$modulebookcontent; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where moduleorganisation=".$moduleorganisation; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where lrcmaterials=".$lrcmaterials; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where moduledifficulty=".$moduledifficulty; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where modulesimilarity=".$modulesimilarity; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where contentinteresting=".$contentinteresting; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where previousknowledge=".$previousknowledge; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where understoodassessmentrequirements=".$understoodassessmentrequirements; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where assessmentmethod=".$assessmentmethod; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where markedwork=".$markedwork; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where ML_interestforsubject=".$ML_interestforsubject;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where ML_contentclear=".$ML_contentclear; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where ML_appropriateteachingpace=".$ML_appropriateteachingpace; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where ML_reachableforadvice=".$ML_reachableforadvice;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where ML_helpfulfeedback=".$ML_helpfulfeedback; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L1_interestforsubject=".$L1_interestforsubject; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L1_contentclear=".$L1_contentclear;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L1_appropriateteachingpace=".$L1_appropriateteachingpace; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L1_reachableforadvice=".$L1_reachableforadvice; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L1_helpfulfeedback=".$L1_helpfulfeedback;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L2_interestforsubject=".$L2_interestforsubject; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L2_contentclear=".$L2_contentclear; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L2_appropriateteachingpace=".$L2_appropriateteachingpace;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L2_reachableforadvice=".$L2_reachableforadvice; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where L2_helpfulfeedback=".$L2_helpfulfeedback; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where moduleleader=".$moduleleader;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where lecturer1=".$lecturer1; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where lecturer2=".$lecturer2; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where indpstudy=".$indpstudy; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where attendance=".$attendance;
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where bestfeatures=".$bestfeatures; 
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where improvemodule=".$improvemodule;


queryDatabase($queryString);
?>


<?php CRUDheader("Delete Student Answers"); ?>

<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="content">
<p>Student answers deleted</p>  
</div>  

</div><?php CRUDmain(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `TRUNCATE TABLE studentanswers`? If you were to select specific rows to delete, the correct syntax is `DELETE FROM studentanswers WHERE column1 = value1`

Comment: `delete * from` is not valid sql syntax. delete does not accept a field list, because you can't delete individual fields - you can only delete entire rows, meaning ALL fields get deleted. `delete from table` is the proper syntax

Comment: @Mave would truncate delete the rows or the table? sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` empties the table keeping the structure intact. The `DROP` command drops and deletes the entire table, including structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've made this a lot harder than it is.

As @Mave suggested, you can simply `TRUNCATE TABLE studentanswers`.

Assuming you want to do it with delete, you were close with `delete *` but that is not the correct way to state it:

```
DELETE FROM STUDENTANSWERS
```

will do the trick.

If you had some kind of preconfigured query input that included a `WHERE` you could do

```
DELETE FROM STUDENTANSWERS WHERE 1=1
```

to delete all rows.

Answer (score 0):

The only query that's being run is the very last one that is assigned before the queryDatabase($queryString). You could cut out all the $queryString = "delete..." before the last one and your code would be doing the same thing.

Functionally, this is doing the same thing:

```
$queryString = "A"; //This does nothing because $queryString gets reset on the next line
$queryString = "B"; //This does nothing because $queryString gets reset on the next line
$queryString = "C"; //This does nothing because $queryString gets reset on the next line
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where improvemodule=".$improvemodule;
queryDatabase($queryString);
```

Back to your question. To delete all rows you can just do:

```
$queryString = "delete from studentanswers where 1=1;
queryDatabase($queryString);
```